# how to show array of objects in json format

Tags: php, json

I have formatted the output like

```
{"main" : { "membersdetails": [{result:SMS message(s) sent},  
      {result:SMS message(s) sent},{result:SMS message(s) sent}]}}
```

> Error is: {result: SMSmessage(s----------------------^Expecting
>   'STRING', }'

What should be done to make it correct.

Comment: your json is not valid this `result` and `SMS message(s) sent` should be in double quotes `"`

Comment: Yeah try this

{main : { membersdetails: [{result:"SMS message(s) sent"},{result:"SMS message(s) sent"},{result:"SMS message(s) sent"}]}}

Comment: Thanks . got the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is *not* to produce JSON strings by hand. Instead, let `json_encode` do it for you:

Example: ([live copy](https://ideone.com/S5CT82))

```
$data = array(
    main => array(
        membersdetails => array(
            array(
                result => 'SMS message(s) sent'
            ),  
            array(
                result => 'SMS message(s) sent'
            ),  
            array(
                result => 'SMS message(s) sent'
            )
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:

```
{"main":{"membersdetails":[{"result":"SMS message(s) sent"},{"result":"SMS message(s) sent"},{"result":"SMS message(s) sent"}]}}
```

Comment: seriously that effort for a question going to delete in couple of days :)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: Took two minutes, and will hopefully be useful to the OP (and the question may not get deleted).